# Show then that the inequality $(z-x)\int_{y}^zf(u)du≥(z-y)\int_{x}^zf(u)du$ holds for any $0 ≤ x < y < z.$

Tags: integration, functions, inequality

> **QUESTION:** Let $f : [0,∞) → \mathbb{R}$ be a non-decreasing continuous function. Show then that the inequality $$(z-x)\int_{y}^zf(u)du≥(z-y)\int_{x}^zf(u)du$$ holds for any $0 ≤ x < y < z.$

**MY APPROACH:** We observe that the integral on the L.H.S. represents the area of the curve $f(x)$ from $y$ to $z$ which is certainly smaller than 
($\because$ the function is non-decreasing) that represented by the integral on the R.H.S which is from $x$ to $z$ $(\because x<y<z)$. And obviously, $(z-x)>(z-y)$, which is in accordance to the given inequality. Now since $x,y,z$ are arbitrary, how do we know that by **how much** one quantity is greater or smaller than the other. The inequality seems like-
$$(greater)(smaller)≥(smaller)(greater)$$

How do I solve this?
Any help will be much appreciated. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By the mean value theorem

\begin{align}
\int_{y}^zf(u)du &=(z-y) f(u) \\
 \int_{x}^zf(u)du &= (z-x) f(v)
\end{align}

Where $u\in [y,z]$ and $v\in [x,z]$. Can you take it from here?

Comment: Does mean value theorem apply to integrals too! I didn't know.. then your statement says $f(u)≥f(v)$ which indeed is true (as the function is non decreasing).. but I didn't understand how you applied the mean value theorem to integrals.. can you please tell me that?

Comment: Absolutely. You can check it [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mean_value_theorem#First_mean_value_theorem_for_definite_integrals)

Comment: Thanks a lot

Comment: You're welcome :)

Answer (score 2):

Consider the function
$$
g(w) = \dfrac{\int_w^z f(u)du}{z-w}
$$
with $ w \in (0,z)$. Then 
$$
g'(w) = \dfrac{-f(w)(z-w)+\int_w^z f(u)du}{(z-w)^2} \ge 0
$$
holds if
$$
\int_w^z f(u)-f(w) du \ge 0.
$$
But $f$ is non-decreasing, so $f(u)\ge f(w)$, so the integrand is positive, and $g(w)$ is an increasing function. That implies your inequality, which is equivalent to $g(y) \ge g(x)$ for $0 \le x < y < z$.